# Add trigger to WordPress User Role select OR run JS on change

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, hook-wordpress

I created a custom User Role and need to detect a change when creating a new user when the role is set to `lessee`. If there is a way to add a trigger to the WordPress creates using a `filter` or `action` that would work, or to detect the change in JS using the `event listener`.

I have the `id` of this `select` and just need to detect when it changes to `lessee` to run a custom JS function.

```
<select name="role" id="role">
 <option value="lessee">Lessee</option>
 <option selected="selected" value="subscriber">Subscriber</option>
 <option value="contributor">Contributor</option>
 <option value="author">Author</option>
 <option value="editor">Editor</option>
 <option value="administrator">Administrator</option>            
</select>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `set_user_role()` hook. [Source.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/set_user_role)

This hook will trigger when a user role is changed. You can conditionally write logic that will run only if the role that the user was changed FROM is 'lessee' by checking to see if that role was in the `$old_roles` array

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'custom_user_change_function', 10, 3 );

function custom_user_change_function( $user_id, $role, $old_roles ) 
{
    if(in_array('lessee', $old_roles)){
       //your code
    }
}
```